# How to get coefficients from exponential model

Tags: r, model, exponential-distribution

I have data $y$ (contain some NA) and $x$ and i want to fitted an exponential model that follow the function:

$$y=A \exp(B\cdot x)+C$$

What function in R that can estimate the value of $A$, $B$, and $C$?

Any lead is really appreciate. Thank you

```
pic<-seq(1,118,1)
dput(dn[1])
list(c(144.433516340355, 92.5385386764545, 327.770374866057, 
327.770374866057, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 170.441960081272, 170.441960081272, 170.441960081272, 
52.3799904961735, 52.3799904961735, 47.6419464982868, 49.9506784150893, 
47.6419464982868, 56.070994493224, 56.070994493224, 49.2276037954582, 
49.2276037954582, 49.2830931805204, 49.2830931805204, 49.2830931805204, 
51.9047324413254, 51.9047324413254, 126.11428935075, 126.11428935075, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 150.975938191117, 150.975938191117, 
158.953072765745, 138.381650035402, 158.953072765745, 126.587791465982, 
126.587791465982, 118.106366073124, 118.106366073124, 118.106366073124, 
104.021885768433, 104.021885768433, 98.0088831979226, 98.0088831979226, 
129.001137743296, 114.215283563362, 129.001137743296, 143.962601820768, 
143.962601820768, 142.186312029785, 142.186312029785, 153.731278359558, 
153.731278359558, 153.731278359558, 147.952764941463, 147.952764941463, 
144.623432713586, 152.098954701198, 144.623432713586, 144.941784665593, 
144.941784665593, 122.726365710622, 122.726365710622, 94.2142608356051, 
94.2142608356051, 94.2142608356051, 80.2924708761379, 80.2924708761379, 
86.4838278090832, 88.9508681900312, 86.4838278090832, 110.427798502967, 
110.427798502967, 135.620751217501, 135.620751217501, 156.943734529467, 
156.943734529467, 156.943734529467, 164.740181622801, 164.740181622801, 
180.681309112803, 190.841882888453, 180.681309112803, 195.226787310429, 
195.226787310429, 185.144893673115, 185.144893673115, 195.158616913913, 
195.158616913913, 195.158616913913, 218.62652080481, 218.62652080481, 
238.50861273641, 238.50861273641, 285.221069580608, 248.000690439839, 
285.221069580608, 347.243062952383, 347.243062952383, 452.807072061844, 
452.807072061844))

sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
system code page: 949

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] optimx_2020-4.2   zoo_1.8-8         spDataLarge_0.5.0 spData_0.3.8      sf_0.9-6         
 [6] akima_0.6-2.1     raster_3.3-13     gdalUtils_2.0.3.2 rgdal_1.5-16      sp_1.4-2         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5          cellranger_1.1.0    compiler_4.0.2      pillar_1.4.6       
 [5] R.methodsS3_1.8.1   R.utils_2.10.1      class_7.3-17        iterators_1.0.13   
 [9] tools_4.0.2         lifecycle_0.2.0     tibble_3.0.3        lattice_0.20-41    
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.3     rlang_0.4.7         foreach_1.5.1       DBI_1.1.0          
[17] rstudioapi_0.11     parallel_4.0.2      xfun_0.18           e1071_1.7-4        
[21] dplyr_1.0.2         generics_0.0.2      vctrs_0.3.4         classInt_0.4-3     
[25] grid_4.0.2          tidyselect_1.1.0    glue_1.4.2          R6_2.4.1           
[29] readxl_1.3.1        purrr_0.3.4         magrittr_1.5        codetools_0.2-16   
[33] ellipsis_0.3.1      units_0.6-7         numDeriv_2016.8-1.1 KernSmooth_2.23-17 
[37] tinytex_0.26        crayon_1.3.4        R.oo_1.24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially, you need to handle the missing values. This can be done via:

- Replacing the NA values via statistical inference. Eg mean, median or mode
- Regressing on Y with respect to each x feature and replacing it with the average of the predicted values

Your function defined as below:

```
f <- function(x, a, b){ a * exp(b *x) + c }
```

It can be fit using nonlinear least squares

```
fit <- nls(y~f(x,a,b,c),data=data.frame(mydata),start=list(a=1, b=30, c=-0.3))
```

You can acquire the predicted values via:

```
fitted.data <- data.frame(x=x, y=predict(fit, list(x=x))
```

You can acquire the coefficents by:

```
data: parent.frame()
```